# Issue using Where method in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Consider this line of code:

```
List<SIDB_TransactionInformation> transaction = SIDB.SIDB_TransactionInformations
                    .Where(k => k.iscurrent == true & k.objectid == SIDB.func_GetObjectID("dbo.SIDB_Module")).ToList();

List<SIDB_Module> module = SIDB.SIDB_Modules
                    .Where(k => k.moduleid == transaction
                                                .Where(j => j.transactionid == k.moduleid)
                                                .SingleOrDefault().transactionid).ToList();
```

I do have 2 invocation of where method in different collection. First i distinct my list via iscurrent and objectid after that I do have other invocation of where method (for SIDB_Modules) to distinct the list via moduleid where in the the values refer to the transactionid of my previous list. Now i have an error message like this ***Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.***

sorry i'm new in lambda expression. need help badly

Comment: There is a logic error in your first WHERE condition. Use && instead of &. Not sure, though, if that caused the error.

Comment: I build my project without errors i've got this error in runtime.

Comment: Missing a single & does not cause compile errors

Comment: Am I right that you're trying to find all modules that contain transactions where `iscurrent == true` and `objectid == some module id`?

Comment: No, he wants a list of transactions that have these specs.. From that list he wants to extract certain modules.. :)

Comment: @Rob : Just a little info. You dont have to explicitly check "k.isCurrent == true". You can write like this as well : Where(k => k.iscurrent && k.objectid == SIDB.func_GetObjectID(). And yes, don't forget AND condition is "&&" not "&".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're trying to do a join between `SIDB_TransactionInformations` and `SIDB.SIDB_Modules`. If so, try

```
var objectID = SIDB.func_GetObjectID("dbo.SIDB_Module");

List<SIDB_Module> modules = (from module in SIDB.SIDB_Modules
  join transaction in SIDB.SIDB_TransactionInformations on module.moduleid equals transaction.transactionid
  where transaction.iscurrent && transaction.objectid == objectID
  select module).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
List<SIDB_Module> module = SIDB
    .SIDB_Modules
    .Where(k => transaction.Any(j => j.transactionid == k.moduleid))
    .ToList();
```

Make a list of `SIDB_Modules` where there is a transaction whose `transactionid` is equal to the `moduleid`. LINQ to Sql might have an issue with Any, I don't remember, if it does you can rewrite it with an extra step like this

```
var transactionIds = transaction.Select(j => j.transactionid);
List<SIDB_Module> module = SIDB
    .SIDB_Modules
    .Where(k => transactionIds.Contains(k.moduleid))
    .ToList();
```

If performance is an issue you might consider going with the second method and putting `transactionIds` into something that implements `ISet<T>` and has a constant time lookup.